# What is the cryptic part at the end of a solidity contract bytecode?

Tags: solidity, remix, evm, solc, assembly

Given the following contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Simple {
    bytes32 public v;
    function set(bytes32 _v) {
        v = _v;
    }
}
```

When disassembling, neither `remix`, `solc` or `evm` can properly intepret the trailing end of the code. Additionally, the code seems unreachable (it follows a JUMP instruction), and what it seems to do doesn't make much sense.

Similar trailing code is produced when compiling with `solc` and `remix`, prefixed and suffixed similarly but contents are slightly different:

```
 00a165627a7a72305820...0029
```

In disassembly, the prefixing bytecode is intepreted by all as:

```
 stop
 log1
 push6 0x627a7a723058 
 sha3
 ...
```

---

When compiled with `remix`, the "assembly" field in the web GUI describes the part as a ".data" tag:

```
[...]
 SSTORE             v = _v
      POP           v = _v
    tag 10          function set(bytes32 _v) {\n        ...
      JUMPDEST          function set(bytes32 _v) {\n        ...
      POP           function set(bytes32 _v) {\n        ...
      JUMP [out]            function set(bytes32 _v) {\n        ...
    .data
```

Thus hinting that this is not code at all, but some form of data field. **If so, what is this used for?**, generally and in this specific example?

---

- **remix:** 0.4.14+commit.c2215d46.Emscripten.clang
- **evm:** 1.7.0-unstable (git commit 3d32690b)
- **solc:** 0.4.14-develop.2017.7.27+commit.16ca1eea.Linux.g++

Runtime bytecode (from `remix`):

```
60606040526000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ffffffff1680637c2efcba146047578063db80813f146075575b600080fd5b3415605157600080fd5b60576099565b60405180826000191660001916815260200191505060405180910390f35b3415607f57600080fd5b6097600480803560001916906020019091905050609f565b005b60005481565b80600081600019169055505b505600a165627a7a72305820e62ffd25aaa1132d83ae4470e9f3991cb237178c38401db1857b9417b74603560029
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the [Swarm](http://swarm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) hash.  It is documented at https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/metadata.html

Extract follows

> #### Contract Metadata
>
> The Solidity compiler automatically generates a JSON file, the
> contract metadata, that contains information about the current
> contract. It can be used to query the compiler version, the sources
> used, the ABI and NatSpec documentation in order to more safely
> interact with the contract and to verify its source code.
>
> The compiler appends a Swarm hash of the metadata file to the end of
> the bytecode (for details, see below) of each contract, so that you
> can retrieve the file in an authenticated way without having to resort
> to a centralized data provider.

The format looks like this:

[image]

If you were to separately upload the metadata file to Swarm then future users of your contract could find it via this reference in the contract code.

#### Update Aug 2019

Since solidity 0.5.9, the metadata format looks like this:

[image: solidity 0.5.9]

And also a word of caution:

> The compiler currently uses the “swarm version 0” hash of the metadata,
> but this might change in the future, so do not rely on this sequence to
> start with 0xa2 0x65 'b' 'z' 'z' 'r' '0'. We might also add additional data to this CBOR structure, so the best option is to use a proper CBOR parser.

Comment: In solidity 0.5.10, I see `0xa2` instead of `0xa1` for the first byte and `0x32` instead of `0x29` for the last byte

Comment: **Update**: Indeed they upgraded the [contract metadata spec](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.11/metadata.html) in solidity 0.5.9.