# What is the keccak256 reference in opcodes from solc?

Tags: solidity, solc, compiler

Opcodes - 
Opcodes:

> PUSH1 0x60 PUSH1 0x40 MSTORE CALLVALUE ISZERO PUSH1 0xE JUMPI PUSH1
>   0x0 DUP1 REVERT JUMPDEST PUSH1 0xA0 DUP1 PUSH2 0x1C PUSH1 0x0 CODECOPY
>   PUSH1 0x0 RETURN STOP PUSH1 0x60 PUSH1 0x40 MSTORE PUSH1 0x4
>   CALLDATASIZE LT PUSH1 0x3F JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 CALLDATALOAD PUSH29
>   0x100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 SWAP1 DIV
>   PUSH4 0xFFFFFFFF AND DUP1 PUSH4 0xC9116B69 EQ PUSH1 0x44 JUMPI
>   JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 REVERT JUMPDEST CALLVALUE ISZERO PUSH1 0x4E
>   JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 REVERT JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x54 PUSH1 0x6A JUMP
>   JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x40 MLOAD DUP1 DUP3 DUP2 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 ADD SWAP2
>   POP POP PUSH1 0x40 MLOAD DUP1 SWAP2 SUB SWAP1 RETURN JUMPDEST PUSH1
>   0x0 PUSH2 0x370 SWAP1 POP SWAP1 JUMP STOP LOG1 PUSH6 0x627A7A723058
>   **KECCAK256 PUSH20 0x982391380BF2F8F878474D86DEC86AD0305FF533** 0xd7 0xb9
>   PUSH28 0xD93A3F18E8ACEFB40029000000000000000000000000000000000000

Code -

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract d8 {

    function myBalance() pure public returns (uint) {
        return 880;
    }

}
```

How to get -

```
solc --opcodes d8.sol
```

I assumed at first it was the source code hashed but apparently not after I checked here - https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html

So it must be a hash of something.

Does anyone know?

Comment: You can find an answer here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23525/what-is-the-cryptic-part-at-the-end-of-a-solidity-contract-bytecode. Briefly, the whole part after stop is a read-only field that is added by the solidity compiler.